# Made-for-TV Nickelodean movie with a group of young teens and one adult

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for for the name of a made for TV movie (live action) that was shown on the Nickelodeon channel some time during the mid 90's (some time between 1994 and 1998).

What I remember:

- The movie revolved around a group of kids-young teens.
- One of the girls was some kind of fire charmer (I remember one scene where she shows off by making small flames shoot out of her fingertips)
- At one point the group tries to cross a desert and comes to a door. On the other side of the door is a raised sand path, if you don't take the path you would fall into a ditch filled with mines. The mine field looks endless and the characters have to find a way to open the door to pass.
- I think there may have been a sand surfing scene at some point.
- I seem to remember the group of kids had one adult (a big burly guy) who was basically their bodyguard. It's very possible he gets killed or captured near the end of the movie while trying to defend the kids.

Comment: A quick scan of wikipedia gives me the following two shows, I'm not sure if either is what you wanted but it seems Nick didn't have a lot of scifi based shows.  Hope this helps! 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Eye_(TV_series)

Comment: Sadly those don't seem to match... The tomorrow people was a full series, and The Third eye is too early to fit. This movie was a 1 shot thing and it would have only been 90min-2hours long.

Comment: I've been searching for years trying to figure this one out. Do you remember a part where the "body guard" was fighting in somewhat of a bar-scene? The only parts of the film that stick out in my mind are desert surfing and two teens with a big guy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found it. I'd been searching for years trying to figure this one out. Do you remember a part where the "bodyguard" was fighting in somewhat of a bar-scene? The only parts of the film that stick out in my mind are desert surfing and two teens with a big guy.

It's called *[Doom Runners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0135997/)*.

[image: Front and back cover of Doom Runners case]

> In a post-apocalyptic world, a group of children move from one uncertain world to another in their quest for sanctuary.

### Promo

Comment: YES! That has to be it. Thank you so much for finding this. I've been looking for this for a while with no luck, I was sure someone on here would eventually find it.